Getting 404 page when using NextResponse.next() in the Next.js 14 middleware
I'm facing a problem with middleware when using NextResponse.next() method in the Next.js 14 app router, here is a code snippet about the code that i'm using in the middleware
if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard")) {
    if (!accessToken && !refreshToken) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/adminLogin", request.url))
    }
    return NextResponse.next();
}

I'm trying to continue to the next route handler by using NextResponse.next() and i expected to be redirected to the dashboad page

Just to be clear .. have you implemented  the /adminLogin route correctly ? Maybe a little folder structure could help to understand the 404

When I visited the route manually it worked correctly, and I checked the request URL from the network tab which was matches the correct url

Does it happens in production or development or both ? Also why use case sensitive urls it won't work since next js considers adminLogin and adminlogin the same urls ?

I haven't tried it in production yet, this problem happens in the development env.
The real problem is in the "NextResponse.next()" statement when the above condition is escaped, so I don't think the problem is from the case of the word letters

Could you please provide reproducible code as the snippet you provided works perfectly  check this https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/long-flower-vvth8t?file=%2Fmiddleware.ts%3A5%2C31

hey @Sanmeet I found the solution, you can see my answer below

I found the solution and the problem cause, the middleware that I'm using in my code is like
export default async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard")) {
    if (!accessToken && !refreshToken) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/adminLogin", request.url))
    }
    return NextResponse.next();
  }
  return i18nMiddleware(request);
}

and the file structure is like
├- src/
|  ├- app/
|     ├- [locale]/
|        ├- dashboard/
|    
├  middleware.ts

So the real problem is when the user is authenticated or has a refresh token I'm returning NextResponse.next() which stops the middleware without launching the i18nMiddleware.
I don't know how i18nMiddleware deals with the default locale but I think it changes the path from https://domainName/en/dashboard to https://domainName/dashboard after rendering so no errors happen because the request is sent to the right path which is /en/dashboard

I understand now that the issue was related to the middleware function implementation using i18n middleware. Next time, it would be helpful to ensure the code is reproducible ( you should have shared the full middleware fn implementation ). That said, I'm glad the problem was resolved in the end.

Welcome and please close this question since your issue was resolved !

I think the question needs one more vote to be closable
